# php-mysql : concat query in below code and manipulation of code

Tags: php, mysql

**here is my code**

```
<?php
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
$result = array();

include 'conn.php';

//$rs1 = "select CONCAT(id,' ',firstname) AS password FROM users";

$rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from users");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);


$result["total"] = $row[0];
$rs = mysql_query("select * from users limit $offset,$rows");


$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

and my output is

```
ID   firstname     lastname  password*
 1    john          abc 
 2    don           def
 3    man           ghi
```

I want password to cancat with id+firstname.. help me in above code please...

Comment: Dont use mysql_query more.Try PDO

Answer (score 2):

Corrected Code:

```
<?php
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
$result = array();

include 'conn.php';

//$rs1 = "select CONCAT(id,' ',firstname) AS password FROM users";

$rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from users");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);


$result["total"] = $row[0];
$rs = mysql_query("select *, CONCAT(id, firstname, password) AS pwd  from users limit $offset,$rows");


$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Whenever I see string concats in MySQL, I wish that they would include the `||` string operation from oracle which makes it so quick to write string concats.

Comment: but no change in oputput :/

Comment: You need to access `$row['pwd']` because, we have used alias.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent i dint get u